# TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.date)

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo

Hi i would like to get a date field after doing a process on an invoice:
those are my functions that i have developed:

```
def get_origins_date_invoice(self, name):
    return ', '.join(set(filter(None,
                (datetime(l.origin_date) for l in self.lines))))


@property
def origin_date(self):
    if isinstance(self.origin, self.__class__):
        return self.origin.invoice.invoice_date
    else:
        return " "
```

but it gives me this error:

```
    (datetime(l.origin_date) for l in self.lines))))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.date).
```

How i can resolve this error.

ps : I have try `(str(l.origin_date) for l in self.lines)))).strftime()` but it gives me also an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that somewhere above this you have `import datetime.datetime as datetime` and that you are calling the [`datetime` class constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)

With that said, `datetime()` takes integers and converts them to datetimes.

I would suggest you try

```py
return ', '.join(set(filter(None,
                (str(type(l.origin_date)) for l in self.lines))))
```

Which will tell you what class `l.origin_date` is.  With that information, you can figure out how to display it.

Comment: Cargos, i have tried that and it gives me this error     (type(l.origin_date) for l in self.lines))))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, type found

Comment: I updated my answer with the fix